# Square RootComplex Number and which branch can be used for integration contour?

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-analysis

What is the definition of the square root of a complex number and which branch of the square root one can use for the integration contour.

For example if we have the following square root.
$$\sqrt{(w-a^2)(w-1/a^2)}$$
For this example which branch can be used for integration contour.

Answer (score 1):

All branches of the square root (there are infinitely many) are possible to be used. But which is used for specific calculations, such as contour integrals, depends on the problem itself. Often, say if you're evaluating an improper real integral, then you'll have the ability to choose a branch of the square root when you turn it into a contour integral, and you'd typically choose a branch that makes the contour integral easiest to work with.

Comment: @ Christopher thanks for your value able comments. What things is making me confused is to decide how to choose a branch. what you think for the above mention square root, where w is the complex number.